# Link a layer with a shape/vector mask in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, background, shapes, mask

Simple question that I can't find the answer to.

I have a layer with a photo that I got off the internet. I want this layer to have rounded corners. So I draw a rectangle with rounded corners in photoshop. Just like the color is linked to the vector mask (that is the rounded corner rectangle), I would think I can link the layer to the vector mask. However, after all my research I cannot find how. Can anybody help link a layer to a vector mask/shape?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its easy, called **Clipping Mask**.

Just put your "**photo**" layer on top of the "**rounded corner**" rectangle layer, in the layers panel (F7). Right-click on the "photo" layer, select "Create Clipping Mask".

**EDIT**

[From this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/57159/how-to-use-clipping-masks-in-photoshop/), I'm summarizing the steps

1. Assuming you have a new document created, import the **photo** layer into Photoshop.
2. Create a new layer below **photo** layer, in layers panel (F7).
3. Draw rectangle by selecting "rounded corner" option, inside "shape" tool. Specify radius.
4. Place both layers in same area on canvas.
5. Right-click on **photo** layer (in **layers** panel), select "Create Clipping Mask" option.

..and you are done!

Comment: Could you sum up the instructions found at the link you posted? This Q&A site aims to provide answers, not links to answers (which might potentially not be available any more in the future).

Comment: I knew it was simple. Hard to find any instructions for simple PS tasks on Google

Answer (score 0):

put your photo layer under your triangle and then just in between the two layers click whilst holding alt. This will use the rectangle as the frame of the image (I think is called clipping mask)